# Twitter Rate Limits and Cron caching with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, cron, whenever

I have a small rails app on Heroku that pulls in my client's latest Tweet to display on all pages. It is hitting Twitter rate limits already. I'm trying to come up with a solution. Would the following be a sensible approach ...

Use a cron gem like [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to pull down the latest Tweet every minute and write it to a file, then have pages pull the Tweet from that file instead of directly from Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is one possibility. Or you could use [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) to store the tweets, for example using Memcached. This will also make your app faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the specific rate limits on twitter, but if they're expressed in requests/minute then the cron job might work. Whatever you do, you need to stop letting incoming traffic drive your requests. Typically you'd create a queue and have a single worker pull requests off of it.  That worker would take care of rate limiting itself so you don't go over.

API rate limits are a necessary evil. Maybe you can make a gem to help other folks easily throttle themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using memcache to cache the requests:

```
latest_tweet = Rails.cache.read "latest_tweet"
if !latest_tweet
   latest_tweet = Twitter.user_timeline("sometwitterusername").first.text 
   Rails.cache.write("latest_tweet", latest_tweet, :expires_in => 5.minutes)
end
```